# How to select the lowest and highest value joined in one row postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in a similar format as this

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

And i want to get a row per type with the highest price and the lowest price like so, also the variety should be taken form the row with the highest price

```
+--------+------------+-------+-------+
| type   | variety    | min   | max   |
+--------+------------+-------+-------+
| apple  | limbertwig |  0.24 |  2.87 |
| orange | navel      |  9.36 |  3.59 |
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 |  2.14 |
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 |  2.55 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------+
```

What is the best way to achieve this using Postgres?

I found this site: [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), but it's not quite what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find fruits with the lowest price:

```
select distinct on (type) type, variety, price
from fruits
order by 1, 3;

 type   | variety  | price 
--------+----------+-------
 apple  | fuji     |  0.24
 cherry | bing     |  2.55
 orange | valencia |  3.59
 pear   | bartlett |  2.14
(4 rows)
```

Find fruits with the highest price:

```
select distinct on (type) type, variety, price
from fruits
order by 1, 3 desc;

 type   |  variety   | price 
--------+------------+-------
 apple  | limbertwig |  2.87
 cherry | chelan     |  6.33
 orange | navel      |  9.36
 pear   | bradford   |  6.05
(4 rows)
```

Combine the two queries:

```
select 
    f1.type, 
    f1.variety min_variety, f1.price min_price, 
    f2.variety max_variety, f2.price max_price
from (
    select distinct on (type) type, variety, price
    from fruits
    order by 1, 3) f1
join (
    select distinct on (type) type, variety, price
    from fruits
    order by 1, 3 desc) f2
on f1.type = f2.type

 type   | min_variety | min_price | max_variety | max_price 
--------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------
 apple  | fuji        |      0.24 | limbertwig  |      2.87
 cherry | bing        |      2.55 | chelan      |      6.33
 orange | valencia    |      3.59 | navel       |      9.36
 pear   | bartlett    |      2.14 | bradford    |      6.05
(4 rows)
```

---

Alternative for those who cannot use Postgres with its great features:

```
select 
    f1.type, 
    f1.variety min_variety, f1.price min_price, 
    f2.variety max_variety, f2.price max_price
from (
    select f.type, f.variety, f.price
    from (
        select type, min(price) minprice
        from fruits group by type
        ) x 
    join fruits f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice
    ) f1
join (
    select f.type, f.variety, f.price
    from (
        select type, max(price) maxprice
        from fruits group by type
        ) x 
    join fruits f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.maxprice
    ) f2
on f1.type = f2.type
order by 1;
```

Comment: Made a sqlfiddle of this solution and seeing it does as expected http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19b44/1

BUT how can i implement this in zend so if at a later day we change from postgres to something else like oracle and it still works (DISTINCT ON is postgres only afaik)

Comment: See the edited answer. I don't use sqlfiddle because it's overloaded recently.

Comment: I managed to squeeze out of sqlfiddle the answer [for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19b44/1).

Comment: Thx alot klin i used your last sql to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Problems of this nature (get the largest, smallest, average, first, last, ... for each group in a table) are best solved with a so-called [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). With window functions you `PARTITION` the data into groups (here on column `"type"`) and then apply some [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) or [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) over the partitions. The function applies over a so-called *frame* in the partition; by default the frame runs from the first row in the partition to the current row but this default can be changed as is done in this answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "type", last_value(variety) OVER w AS variety
       first_value(price) OVER w AS min, last_value(price) OVER w AS max
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY "type" ORDER BY price
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note that the window functions or aggregate functions add columns to the output, just like in the regular case. In the answer above the `DISTINCT` clause is used to get only a single row for each of the "types" of fruit. Without that clause you would get an output row for every input row, with repeated data for every "type" of fruit.

Using window functions also means that you are making only a single scan of the table and not use any temporary tables (as you do with sub-selects or CTE's) or joins. On larger tables this should make a large difference in performance. Also, it scales much better with additional requirements (such as adding the average price to your output).

Comment: Never knew about window howwever it does not seem to work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a6e5/2

Comment: @eirikir and @Hammersholt  The answer needed a `RANGE` clause; answer corrected and explanation added.

Answer (score 2):

Your results table sample has min and max around the wrong way for three of the rows ;)

Another way to do this - similar to answer 1 above, is with CTEs:

```
WITH mini AS (
    select  type
    ,   MIN(price) as minprice
    FROM    fruits
    GROUP BY type
), maxi AS (
    select  type
    ,   MAX(price) as maxprice
    FROM    fruits
    GROUP BY type
)
SELECT  fruits.type
,   fruits.variety as max_variety
,   mini.minprice
,   maxi.maxprice
FROM    fruits
JOIN    mini ON mini.type = fruits.type
JOIN    maxi ON maxi.type = fruits.type AND maxi.maxprice = fruits.price
WHERE   fruits.price = maxi.maxprice
AND fruits.type = maxi.type
ORDER BY fruits.type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT price,(SELECT price FROM uri WHERE price IN ('25.50'))From uri
WHERE price IN ('800');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.